# CorruptModelException during work item execution

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm totally new with the Forge design-automation (V3 Beta)

During the work item execution inside the design-automation framework, the CorruptModelException is thrown.

The model (.rvt) being sent will open without problem in the desktop environment (R2018).

I tried to purge unused and resaved, but it didn't help. Here's the part from the log that tells the problem.

```
[04/17/2019 10:11:16] Found an addIn for registration: xxx.addin
[04/17/2019 10:11:16] Initializing RCE....
[04/17/2019 10:11:16] Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
[04/17/2019 10:11:16] Language not specified, using English as default
[04/17/2019 10:11:18] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 18.0.0.0 (VersionNumber) 2018 (SubVersionNumber) 2018.3
[04/17/2019 10:11:18] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.CorruptModelException: The model could not be opened: Unspecified error
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]  (COleException 0x80004005)
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]    at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(String fileName)
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[04/17/2019 10:11:18]    at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] Process exit code: 4
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] End script phase.
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[04/17/2019 10:11:22] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

One example file I'm tryuing to use can be found from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/chffmh62wlmuwx7/empty.rvt?dl=0

Could someone test, whether he can use this with Revit 2018 design automation.

I'm also a bit confused about Workitem API. The documentation says that I NEED to use 3 legged auth. (which seems to be awfully difficulty as it requires additional signatures in the request (?)...), but the step by step guide shows it with 2-legged, which is otherwise working OK for me too. This is probably not the reason to my difficulties.

Any ideas...?

Comment: can you please confirm if the Revit engine version matches the file version (as you tested locally)? can you please add more details on the workitem, specifically where the input file is coming from? if the problem persists, can you share the problematic file at forge.help email? Please do not send any confidential information,

Comment: The Revit is 2018 in the both ends. Previously I had 2018 main release, but now I updated to 2018.3, and I'm getting still same result. Even tried with blank project.

My files are stored in the Dropbox, and the download phase seems to work OK. I can share the link to the empty project here as well.

Comment: I noticed one detail from the log:

```End downloading file https://www.dropbox.com/s/chffmh62wlmuwx7/empty.rvt?dl=0. 194568 bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\a9d5838fcdba401ca083e1913199b336\empty.rvt.```

It says that it has downloaded less than 0.2MB. What might cause that...

Comment: indeed download/upload from/to Dropbox can be tricky, let me try from here

Comment: Now I tried A360 Drive, pretty much same result, when using a share link: https://autode.sk/2VeaSii. Is there any reliable cloud file source for the use...I mean so that I would avoid using OSS API while I'm prototyping the design automation.

Comment: the link you mentioned above (from Autodesk) will not work, this is not a direct link to the file, but a webpage... any storage should work, but you need to pass the correct headers to access the file, and I know Dropbox has some particularities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link the provided in the comments is not a direct download link. If you click on the link, it takes you to a webpage:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/chffmh62wlmuwx7/empty.rvt?dl=0

The workitem input arguments need a direct download link to be able to process the file correctly. For example, a direct download link to the exact same file is

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/chffmh62wlmuwx7/empty.rvt

Comment: Yes, this seems to do the trick! Although I couldn't figure out where did you actually get the direct link...is it Dropbox business etc. feature...? Or did you get it somehow monitoring the network traffic etc?

Comment: Please see the dropbox documentation about "dl=1":
https://help.dropbox.com/desktop-web/force-download

Note that, it is best to use the final redirect link.